# Computer Architecture, specifically Amdahl's Law

Tags: computer-architecture, parallel-computing

I am currently enrolled in a computer organization and design class, which I am struggling mightily with, and I have a final homework in my class that I need to get a perfect score on. The question I have having issues with is:

> A program has a parallel section that represents 80% of its execution time when run on one processor.
>
> What speedup is achieved when run on two processors?
>
> What is the maximum speedup that can be achieved by adding additional processors?

Am I correct in assuming that for the first part of the question, I should use the formula

1/[(1-P) + (P/S)], where P is .8 and S is 2? This would give me the answer: 1.6667

As far as the second part goes, I'm not sure how to approach it...

Comment: You don't just "use formula", you use them because they mean something. What is $P$ and $S$ ? what are you trying to achieve by using this formula..?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: The only true answer is "we don't know". If the teacher wants you to just apply Amdahl's law they are asking you to be wrong; it does not mean much in this context.

Answer (score 2):

If 'M' fraction of the code can be parallelized, the execution time in case of 'N' processors would be

> `T(N) = T(1)*[(1-M)+(1/N)*M]
>   speedup = T(1)/T(N) = 1/[(1-M)+(1/N)*M]`

So for 2 processors, `speedup = 1/(0.2+0.8/2)`

In the limit, as N tends to infinity, the maximum speedup tends to `1/(1-M)`. So, in this case `maximum speedup = 5`

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law)

Comment: This is a theoretical calculation using a formula that does not apply to parallel computation on real machines.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat simplified (or even superficial) answer is the following:

You have 100% of code, where 80% of it can be parallelized. Let's assume it takes 100 units of time to run the entire code on a single processor.

Assuming 2 processors, in the ideal case, the 80% part is split between them, so it takes 40 units to complete. The entire program will take 20+40=60 units. Of course, it may be that you cannot achieve this ideal speedup due to dependencies.

Now add a third processor. If the parallelable part can be split into three, then it will be completed within $\approx27$ time units.

Comment: This calculation is too naive even for theoretical models. You can  not set up parallel execution with zero overhead, and other factors may impact runtime as well.

Answer (score -3):

In the cyber/ computer world 1 processor + 1 processor does NOT EQUAL 2 Processors. The processors tend to trip over each other or get into the way of each other when trying to do work.

Comment: That is correct but does not answer the question at all.